# Maven JAXB plugin executing only one excecution

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, maven-3, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am trying to generated sources from two `XSD` schemas. My `JAXB` maven plugin looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>GenerateKenexa</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeBindings>
                    <includeBinding>**/jaxb-bindings-kenexa.xml</includeBinding>
                </includeBindings>
                <includeSchemas>
                    <includeSchema>**/KenexaXMLConfiguration.xsd</includeSchema>
                </includeSchemas>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>GenerateTalentQ</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeBindings>
                    <includeBinding>**/jaxb-bindings-talentq.xml</includeBinding>
                </includeBindings>
                <includeSchemas>
                    <includeSchema>**/TalentQXMLConfiguration.xsd</includeSchema>
                </includeSchemas>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The first one gets generated fine. But the second one does not. I see in the maven output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jaxb-plugin:1.1.1:generate (GenerateKenexa) @ online.tests.management ---
[INFO] Compiling file:/D:/Projects/GTIWebApplications/gti_online_tests_management/src/main/resources/xsd/KenexaXMLConfiguration.xsd
[INFO] Writing output to D:\Projects\GTIWebApplications\gti_online_tests_management\target\generated-sources\xjc
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jaxb-plugin:1.1.1:generate (GenerateTalentQ) @ online.tests.management ---
[INFO] files are up to date
```

It says that files are up to date, but they aren't even generated. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem. I have changed the maven `jaxb` plugin into maven `jaxb2` plugin and now everything works. Now my maven configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>GenerateKenexa</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>KenexaXMLConfiguration.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <generatePackage>com.groupgti.onlinetest.kenexa.jaxb</generatePackage>
                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/kenexa</generateDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>GenerateTalentQ</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>TalentQXMLConfiguration.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <generatePackage>com.groupgti.onlinetest.talentq.jaxb</generatePackage>
                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/talentq</generateDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 22):

For people coming in to this question as I did, a year later :/

The problem persists in maven-jaxb2-plugin aswell, it's probably some sort of bug in 0.8.3.
When you generate the files into the same directory, the plugin "thinks" that the files have allready been generated and skips that second execution.

I found that in order to generate the second execution you will have to set the argument

```
<forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
```

In the configuration section.

Comment: It has to mentioned though that meanwhile the use of this forceRegenerate setting is strongly discouraged; See here: https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Do-Not-Use-forceRegenerate

Comment: Recommendation from jaxb : Do not use <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate> and switch to the 0.12.1 or later version of the plugin. https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/Do-Not-Use-forceRegenerate

Answer (score 2):

I am using jaxb2 while still was facing the problem when I reached here. I added the below piece into config from other folks answers and it works now.
For previous answers the part that did the trick should be:

```
<generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/kenexa</generateDirectory>
```

Also a unique execution id is needed

```
<id>GenerateKenexa</id>
```

But different directories make the code lies into two top level packages, so at last I am using:

```
<forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
```

Comment: When using separate directories, you should no longer need <forceRegenerate>, at least not with version 0.12.1 of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend to specify separate output folders for each xsd `<outputdirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc</outputdirectory>`

And second, try to set it up as separate plugin entries, no separate executions:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2</groupId>
...
<includeSchema>**/KenexaXMLConfiguration.xsd...
...
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2</groupId>
...
<includeSchema>**/TalentQXMLConfiguration.xsd...
...
</plugin>
```

Comment: If I separate those into different plugins only last one gets executed, first one does not, and my code does not compile. And where I should add this <outputdirectory>? There is no such element available.